# Svelte: access and manipulate content passed to a slot

Tags: svelte, svelte-3, svelte-component

I'm trying to create a reusable `<Tabs>` component. Here's what I want the API to be:

```html
<Tabs>
  <Tab>
    <TabLabel>First</TabLabel>
    <TabPanel>First tab's content</TabPanel>
  </Tab>

  <Tab>
    <TabLabel>Second</TabLabel>
    <TabPanel>Second tab's content</TabPanel>
  </Tab>
</Tabs>
```

And here's the HTML output I'd expect:

```html
<div>
  <div>
    <div>First</div>
    <div>Second</div>
  </div>

  <div>
    <div>First tab's content</div>
    <div>Second tab's content</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Notice how the content gets rearranged: all the `TabLabel`s and `TabPanel`s get grouped together. I wonder if this kind of rearrangement would be possible in Svelte?

I pondered possible solutions, and I think it would need to happen at the `TabView` level, but don't know how to actually access content passed to `slot` to manipulate it.

Comment: Things like this are very hard to do if not impossible. See these issues: [#5381](https://github.com/sveltejs/svelte/issues/5381), [#4455](https://github.com/sveltejs/svelte/issues/4455)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is certainly not easy, but it is possible.

Whenever you have components that need to do things based on other components around them, you can use `setContex` and `getContext`. Then, you set a store as the context and pass bounded `<div>`s upwards. Finally, you can hide the original and rebuild it using the `@html` tag (to keep it declarative and not have to use any DOM APIs)

Below I have my implementation with some notes. I did it with Typescript, but you can remove all the type annotations if you are not using it. This works with any HTML btw, not just text.

`Tabs.svelte`:

Here we set the context store and build the DOM structure.

```html
<script lang="ts">
    import { setContext } from "svelte";
    import { writable } from "svelte/store";

    const tabs = writable({} as { [label: string]: HTMLDivElement })

    setContext('tabs', tabs)

    $: console.log($tabs);
    
</script>

<div>
    <div>

        {#each Object.keys($tabs) as label}
            <div>
                {@html label}
            </div>
        {/each}
    </div>
        
    <div>
        {#each Object.values($tabs) as panel}
            <div>
                {@html panel?.innerHTML}
            </div>
        {/each}
    </div>
</div>
    
<div style="visibility: hidden;">
    <slot />
</div>
```

`Tab.svelte`:

```html
<script lang="ts">
    import { getContext, setContext } from "svelte";
    import { writable, type Writable } from "svelte/store";

    const tabLabel = writable<HTMLDivElement>(null)
    const tabPanel = writable<HTMLDivElement>(null)

    setContext('label', tabLabel)
    setContext('panel', tabPanel)

    const tabs = getContext('tabs') as Writable<{ [label: string]: HTMLDivElement }[]>

    $: if ($tabLabel) {
        $tabs[$tabLabel.innerHTML] = $tabPanel
    } 
</script>

<slot />
```

`TabLabel.svelte`

```html
<script lang="ts">
    import { getContext } from "svelte";
    import type { Writable } from "svelte/store";

    let slot: HTMLDivElement
    const tabLabelStore = getContext('label') as Writable<HTMLDivElement>
    $: $tabLabelStore = slot
</script>

<div bind:this={slot}>
    <slot />
</div>
```

`TabPanel.svelte`

```html
<script lang="ts">
    import { getContext } from "svelte";
    import type { Writable } from "svelte/store";

    let slot: HTMLDivElement
    const tabPanelStore = getContext('panel') as Writable<HTMLDivElement>
    $: $tabPanelStore = slot
</script>

<div bind:this={slot}>
    <slot />
</div>
```

Note: since I'm using `.innerHTML` the `<div>`s that are wrapping the `<slot/>`s are not a problem, in case you wondered.

It does work, but, even though I've spent a considerable amount of time building this demo, I would encourage against using this. It has too much magic and it is kind of finicky.

Comment: This a complex answer, I wonder if you could expand your code to hide and show the corresponding tab content when tab is clicked.  Also would this work with multiple tab componets on the page?

Comment: You can probably do something in the `{#each...` block to show and hide the tabs. Also, I think this works with multiple instances as long as they are not nested. However, my recommendation is to just avoid this structure altogether. I would probably save the a map of strings to svelte components or something but it depends on the specifics of what you're building.